# grep to a file from one server to another

Tags: linux, grep

I have a grep command like below

```
zgrep '123_ERROR' xyz.gz
```

I got lot of huge results where I cannot see top part.

So what is best way to see entire result

how to export results to a file

```
zgrep '123_ERROR' xyz.gz>>/home/test/testfile.txt
```

i used above command but i do not seem to have permission to create testfile.txt

how to create above file in one other server whose ip is say 111.1.111.111

Comment: Hi an welcome to StackExchange. Unfortunately, it is very unclear what you're asking. Please edit your question to show exactly what you're trying to do (input and expected output), and where you are stuck. Also, to see the 'complete' output, you can just pipe `zgrep` into `less` or `more`.

Comment: I don't know why the IP would affect this.  You've tried to write to a file `/home/test/testfile.txt`  Unless your current user is called `test` you probably don't have access to do this.  You can easily reference your own home directory with `~`.  Eg:  `zgrep '123_ERROR' xyz.gz ~/testfile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do that remotely you can do it this way:

```
ssh 111.1.111.111 zgrep '123_ERROR' xyz.gz | less
```

or

```
ssh 111.1.111.111 zgrep '123_ERROR' xyz.gz \| less
```

The first command greps results and sends back to you while `less` is invoced by your host.

The second command does everything on the remote server (the pipe is sent to the other end).

To be precise if you wish to store the output on your computer you could run:

```
ssh 111.1.111.111 zgrep '123_ERROR' xyz.gz >> local_file
```